# Repeat .then() as often as there are items

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, promise

Suppose I have an array `var numbers = [0, 1, 2]` and an `$http` request.
I want to chain as many `.then()` functions after the `$http.get()` as there are items in `numbers`.  So I want code like

```
//for each item in numbers
.then(function(){
  $http.get(...)
   .then(function(){
     $http.get(...)
      .then(...)
   })
})
```

so that the code runs as

```
.then(
   $http.get(...)
     .then(
        $http.get(...)
          .then(
             $http.get(...)
          )
     )
)
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$http.get().then(function() {
    numbers.forEach(callback);
});
```

Couldn't you just loop thru them? <sub>(hint: the answer is yes)</sub>

With your edit, you need a different loop! Weee…

```
var i = 0; //Mind the scope (thanks @PaulS.) - a function wrapper is a good idea
function callback() {
    if (i++ < numbers.length) $http.get().then(callback);
};
$http.get().then(callback);
```

Comment: of course I want to do more than just displaying the numbers. The `.then()` calls have to be called after each other

Comment: @Clawish Then you can execute a callback function for everything in the loop.

Comment: had to edit the question...

Comment: Watch out for where the closure of `i` happens here, I might've wrapped the whole thing in an _IIFE_